# Less compiler prefixes url with ../ on his own

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have a problem compiling bootstrap less into css.

I am using Visual Studio with Web Compiler extension.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c

The following variables are defined:

```
@icon-font-path:          "fonts/";
@icon-font-name:          "glyphicons-halflings-regular";
```

This is the part that uses variables:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.eot');
}
```

This is the resulting css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
}
```

The problem is that the url gets prefixed with `../`.

What is causing this, how can I get url without prefix - `fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`?

Comment: Are you compiling with the relative URLs option enabled? Else, the Less compiler won't do any modifications to the path.

Comment: Maybe - those are stock bootstrap less files. How do I turn off relative URLs option? Can I turn it off inside some of the less files?

Comment: I've never used Visual Studio or the Web Compiler extension and so can't help with that. In command line that option is enabled using `lessc --relative-urls` (default is disabled).

Comment: Thank you for your help, gave me the tip on what to search for and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, so I am posting here if someone encounters the same problem.

Edit the `compilerconfig.json` and set `relativeUrls` option to `false`.
If not specified, the default value appears to be `true`.

```
  {
    "inputFile": "Bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less",
    "outputFile": "Bootstrap/less/output/bootstrap.css",
    "options": { "relativeUrls": false }
  }
```

This appears to be equivalent to `lessc --relative-urls` when using Web Compiler extension.

Comment: It is interesting that the Web Compiler extension has enabled this option by default. Good that you managed to find it.